ImportError: cannot import name 'Employee' from 'employee' despite files being in the same directory
I am fairly new to coding and Python and I'm facing an issue with importing a class from one Python file to another. The files employee_1.py and company_1.py are in the same directory, but I keep getting an ImportError. Here are the details:
Directory Structure:
C:\Users\trand\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Course\Class and object1
│
├── employee.py
└── company.py

Content of employee_1.py:
print("Executing employee.py")

class Employees:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, salary):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.salary = salary

    def calculate_paycheck(self):
        return self.salary/52

Content of company_1.py
from employee import Employees

class Company: 
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.employees = []

    def add_employee(self, new_employee):
        self.employees.append(new_employee)
    
    def display_employees(self):
        print("Current Employees:")
        for i in self.employees:
            print(i.name, i.lname)
        print("___________________")
    

def main():
    my_company = Company()

    employee1 = Employees("Sarah", "Holder", "50000") 
    my_company.add_employee(employee1)
    employee2 = Employees("Sam", "Taylor", "244000")
    my_company.add_employee(employee2)
    employee3 = Employees("Danny", "Hans", "20000")
    my_company.add_employee(employee3)

    my_company.display_employees 

main()

When I run company_1.py, I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Employee' from 'employee_1' (c:\Users\trand\OneDrive\Desktop)
I have also done the following:

Verified Directory Structure so both employee_1.py and company_1.py are in the same directory.

Cleared Bytecode Files: Removed any __pycache__ directories to ensure no stale bytecode is causing issues.

Correct Import Statement: Ensured that company_1.py is correctly importing Employee from employee_1.


Would really appreciate any help from you guys!

The text for the ImportError includes a reference to the file path c:\Users\trand\OneDrive\Desktop, but your directory structure toward the top of your question shows your code resides at the path C:\Users\trand\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Course\Class and object1. Are you invoking this code within the correct working directory…? Duplicate of Python3.6 ImportError when running script outside the directory. Runs correctly within same directory, among others I’m sure.
